# Replying to a Mailman list using Gmail from digest

Tags: gmail

I'd like to reply to a thread from a mailman list (pytables-users) from Gmail, but I'm not sure exactly how. Do I just hit reply the manually edit the subject line and copy/paste anything relevant from the message I'm replying to? Will Mailman automatically detect that the message belongs in the same thread?

Related questions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/142238/reply-to-mailman-archived-message) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/288995/how-to-participate-in-mailing-list-im-receiving-as-digest).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's being worked on. [Mailman bug #889635](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mailman/+bug/889635)

You can help by voting for this issue.

Now, it will probably take some time for the thing to be implemented in all the mailman servers in the world.

For myself I found it easier to just create a Gmail account for all the list mail, and not using digest.

Answer (score 5):

Another option if you're using Gmail is this:

1. Sign up your primary email address, let's say `foobar12345678901@gmail.com`, for receiving the individual emails instead of digests. Use mail filtering to divert those messages to the appropriate labels.
2. Then sign up on the mailing list in digest mode with `foobar12345678901+DIGEST@gmail.com`.

Gmail strips the + symbol and the text between it and the @ symbol when routing the message.

Emails sent to `foobar12345678901@gmail.com` and `foobar12345678901+DIGEST@gmail.com` will thus both land in the mailbox of `foobar12345678901@gmail.com`. Mailman will treat them as two separate email addresses with two different sets of profile options for single messages versus digests.

Now, when you see something in a digest message to which you care to respond, just go to the label corresponding to the individual message that would have come through and reply to the main thread you care about for proper message threading!

Your mail filter will probably need to look something like this:

```
From: -"listname-l-request@lists.example.com"
To: listname-l@lists.example.com
Skip the Inbox (Archive It) CHECKED
Apply the label: <whatever label you want to use
```

You'll need to replace "listname" and "example.com" above with the name of the list and the mailing domain involved with the mailman mailing list.